# Can 'all' be applied to a list of Maybe?

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to use `all` on a `[Maybe Int]` list?

I know `all (< 9) [2,4,6,8,10]` returns `False`, but that is using a list with just integers.

I am trying to accomplish something similar except with a list that looks like this:
`[Just 3, Just 6, Nothing, Nothing, Just 7]`

I want `all (<=9) [Just 3, Just 6, Nothing, Nothing, Just 7]` to return `True`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
> all (<= Just 9) [Just 3, Just 6, Nothing, Nothing, Just 7]
True
```

This works because `Nothing` is less than any `Just x`.

Alternatively, one can use `catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]` from the `Data.Maybe` module to discard the `Nothing`s, and remove the `Just` wrappers, turning the list into a list of numbers, which can then be handled as usual:

```
> all (<= 9) $ catMaybes [Just 3, Just 6, Nothing, Nothing, Just 7]
True
```

Another alternative: define your own predicate on `Maybe Int`.

```
let p :: Maybe Int -> Bool
    p Nothing = True
    p (Just x) = x <= 9
 in all p [Just 3, Just 6, Nothing, Nothing, Just 7]
```

Even better: define `p` using `maybe`, as [Zeta suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43932415/3234959).

Yet another alternative, using a list comprehension and `and`:

```
and [ x <= 9 | Just x <- [Just 3, Just 6, Nothing, Nothing, Just 7] ]
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like `all (>= Just 1 && <= Just 9) [Just 3, Just 6, Nothing, Nothing, Just 7]`

This doesn't seem to work on Prelude.

Comment: You can use `all (\x -> x>=Just 1 && x<=Just 9) ...` but remember that `Nothing` is the least, so it's not that useful. Use `catMaybes`, or (better) lift the predicate using `maybe` as Zeta showed: `all (maybe True (\x -> x>=1 && x<=9)) ...`

Comment: Thanks! It is useful because I'm making a sudoku solver and there are no zeros in sudoku!

Comment: @RQ14 "This doesn't seem to work on Prelude" -- `import Data.Maybe` will bring `catMaybes` in.

Answer (score 13):

Sure. `maybe True (< 9)`. [`maybe default func`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maybe) uses the given function `func` if you have `Just`, or the `default` if you have `Nothing`:

```
ghci> all (maybe True (< 9))  [Just 3, Just 6, Nothing, Nothing, Just 7]
True
```

You can use that to write your `allMaybe` function:

```
allMaybe :: (a -> Bool) -> [Maybe a] -> Bool
allMaybe p = all (maybe True p)
```

Or we could "lift" your predicate to `Maybe`:

```
liftP :: (a -> Bool) -> Maybe a -> Bool
liftP _ Nothing  = True
liftP p (Just x) = p x
-- or simply 
-- liftP p = maybe True p

allMaybe' p = all (liftP p)
```

But that only hides the underlying `maybe` away.

Comment: Lifting the predicate with `maybe` would indeed be the best approach, IMO.

Answer (score 13):

A slightly more esoteric solution than those by [chi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43932384/2751851) and [Zeta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43932415/2751851) would be using [`Compose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html) so that `all` sees the two layers as a single structure containing numbers:

```
GHCi> import Data.Functor.Compose
GHCi> all (<=9) $ Compose [Just 3, Just 6, Nothing, Nothing, Just 7]
True
```